# Algorithm for creating a score based on percent and distance

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to calculate a score based on two pieces of data: percentage and distance. Both of these are used in ranking colors.

`Percentage` can range from 0 to 100, and can be a decimal. In fact, most of the time it is a decimal and not a whole number. Percentage is important because it means there is more of a color occurring in an image.

`Distance` can also be from 0 to 100 and is also can be a decimal. The distance is calculated in a more complex way... essentially each color has a true value and a mapped value. The mapped value is a pre-set color, so in simple terms `true_color - map_color = distance`. The distance is how different the true color is from the mapped color.

My problem seems to be in how to weight the numbers so that a high percentage with a smaller distance should rank higher than a high percentage with a bigger distance. Here are some attempts that I've made:

This is how I believe the data should be ordered because it puts weight on percentage with distance (accuracy) in mind rather than just percentage.

```
7 percent, 0.5 distance  = 140 (1st)
4 percent, 0.02 distance = 200 (2nd)
2 percent, 1 distance    = 200 (3rd)
10 percent, 8 distance   = 125 (4th)
10 percent, 50 distance  = 125 (5th)
```

However, I keep coming up with this order based on my formula:

```
t = 100 // max distance possible

4 percent * (t / 0.02 distance) = 20,000
7 percent * (t / 0.5 distance)  = 1400
2 percent * (t / 1 distance)    = 200
10 percent * (t / 8 distance)   = 125
10 percent * (t / 50 distance)  = 20
```

**Any ideas on how to fix this?**

Comment: Would this be suitable? `pct + 2(100-dst)`: highest values come first.

Comment: @trincot I actually think that works. I did the math and the set orders correctly. `percentage + 2 * (100 - distance)`. If you put that as an answer I can give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest this formula:

```
percentage + 2 * (100 - distance)
```

If later you still need adjustments, you can play a bit with the factor **2**.

Another tactic might be to apply the square root to **distance**:

```
percentage + 20 * (10 - sqrt(distance))
```

This will make the increase of **distance** having more effect when **distance** is small, than when it already is big. But it does put your first two colours in reversed order.

Comment: What would be the inverse of the square root option? I only ask so I can try all three options on the result set and see how they order (even though the first should suffice). It's more of a curiosity thing... thank you for your help!

Comment: @stwhite: the "inverse" of square root is square. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: @JimMischel I guess what I meant is the inverse of this => "distance having more effect when distance is small". So the distance having less effect when it is small than when it is large. If that's the same as what you're saying then we can forget about it, haha.